# Allowing users to download very large files in IIS (10GB+)

Tags: iis

What solution are people using to enable users to download large files in application running on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

For the web application, there is a cap on the maximum file request size and also the request timeout, this limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are caused by users who post large files to the server.

As far as I know, the maximum length of content in a request can be specified via the `maxAllowedContentLength`, but `maxAllowedContentLength` has type uint, its maximum value is 4,294,967,295 bytes = 4 gb, this does not meet your requirements. or you can consider splitting this large file into several parts.